# Replacing value with string in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-geocoder

i want to replace the value of placemark.name with the string MyPostition in a textfield station but this lines of code doesn't work any suggestions please

```
 _station.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placemark.name];
 _station.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"MyPosition"];
```

Comment: I think are you tried this

    `_station.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyPosition %@",placemark.name];`

Comment: can you make this question bit clear??

Comment: use stringbyreplacingOccuranceofString

Comment: you got error or something than please give detail for that also

Comment: what the output do u need bro

Comment: i want mypostion take the value of placemark.name and just display for me mypostion in textfield @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If `MyPosition` is a variable from which you want to set the value then please remove the `"` from this variable as follows:

```
_station.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",MyPosition];
```

Update as understood by your requirement:

```
_station.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placemark.locality];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
_station.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placemark.locality];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Its may be useful to you

```
    NSString *str = @"This is a MyPosition";

   str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MyPosition"
                                 withString:@"duck"];
```